# What is the best way to understand the uniform topology generated uniform metric?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In $\Bbb{R}^\infty$ ($\Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R} \times ....$),

What is the basis element generated by unifrom metric with radius 1?

I think (-1,1) x ( -1,1) x (-1,1) .... is not an basis element since supreme can be 1.

What is the basis element then?

is (-1,1) x ( -1,1) x (-1,1)... open set if it is countably many?

Answer (score 1):

Let $z$ be the zero sequence. If $B(0,1)$ is the open ball of radius $1$ (in the uniform metric) centred at $z$, then

$$B(0,1)=\bigcup_{n\ge 2}\left(-1+\frac1n,1-\frac1n\right)^\infty\;,\tag{1}$$

so it is the union of countably many powers of open intervals. It is not itself a product of open intervals, however.

To see that $(1)$ is correct, note first that if $x\in\left(-1+\frac1n,1-\frac1n\right)^\infty$, then $\sup_n|x_n|\le 1-\frac1n<1$, so $x\in B(0,1)$. On the other hand, if $x\in B(0,1)$, then $\sup_n|x_n|<1$, so there is an $n\ge 2$ such that $x\in\left(-1+\frac1n,1-\frac1n\right)^\infty$.

Comment: Thank you so much  sir. Is "countably many" crucial?

Comment: just one more clarification, if radius is greater than 1, is it going to be countable many powers of entire spaces?

Comment: @jessie: No, countably many isn’t crucial; it is, however, the smallest (infinite) number that will work, and that fact is occasionally useful. \\ If the radius is $r>1$, you can do the same thing: $$B(0,r)=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\left(-r+\frac1n,r-\frac1n\right)^\infty\;.$$